# Constructor and functions not running in C++

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I made **test.cpp** and **test.h** with a constructor and function with `cout` then call them from **main.cpp** to print some text. When running **main.exe**, the text does not appear.

Either I'm missing something fundamental or maybe there's something wrong with my compiler settings.

I've tried with VS Code and Visual Studio 2022, and the same thing happens.

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() { std::cout << "cout from constructor"; }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "cout from print funcion";
    }
};
```

test.h

```
#pragma once

class Test
{
public:
    Test() {}
    void print()
    {
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "cout from main.cpp";

    Test t; //this is not calling constructor
    t.print(); //this is not calling print()

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
[cout from main.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQMq8.png)

Comment: You have two definitions of the class `Test`, one in the header and one in the cpp file. My guess is you're not compiling and linking the cpp file at all, because if you were you'd have multiple definition errors, so the empty functions from the header are all that exist. Add your logs to those and you'll see that.

Comment: Add `#include "test.h"` in test.cpp and compile test.cpp with main.cpp.

Comment: *Either I'm missing something fundamental or maybe there's something wrong with my compiler settings.* Missing something fundamental, I'm afraid. I recommend re-reading the section in your text that covers defining and implementing classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments ensure you are only defining the default constructor and the `print` function *once.* Currently you define both in the header and in the implementation file. The versions in the header file do not print anything.

I would also suggest you terminate debugging prints with a newline to avoid output buffering issues.

If you fix these issues, the output is as expected.

```
% cat test.h
#pragma once

class Test {
public:
    Test();
    void print();
};

% cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

Test::Test() { 
    std::cout << "cout from constructor" << std::endl; 
}
    
void Test::print() {
    std::cout << "cout from print funcion" << std::endl;
}

% cat main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "cout from main.cpp" << std::endl;

    Test t; 
    t.print(); 

    return 0;
}

% g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp main.cpp
% ./a.out
cout from main.cpp
cout from constructor
cout from print funcion
%
```

Comment: Thank you.

It was like everyone said about the empty constructor and function, but a big problem was the way I was trying to run it. I was using "Run Build Task > g++.exe." and then .\main.exe.

It worked when using 
% g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp main.cpp
% ./a.out

Comment: When you have multiple implementation files, you need to compile and link them all to produce an executable. Since your header contained the implementation, leaving out the step of compiling and linking test.cpp "worked" but the results were not as anticipated.